# function doesnt work , cant find my error

Tags: c

this program is used to read a string and to display the string but it doesnt print out anything for some reason..

Function to print string and to read string using pointers and arrays:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


void read_string ( char s[]);
void display_string(char s1[]);

int main()

{//begin main
    char string1[100];
    do
    {
        read_string(string1);
        puts("the string entered is \n");
        display_string(string1);
    } while(string1[0]);

    return 0;
}//end main

void read_string ( char *s)
{
    int i;
    char c;
    for( i = 0;(c = getchar())!= '\n' ; i++)
        s[i] = c;
    s[i] = NULL;
}

void display_string(char *s1)
{
    int i;
    char c;
    for (i =0; s1[i]; i++)
    {
        s1[i] = c;
        putchar(s1[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please indent your code so that it's readable.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The display_string method override the string with c (that is uninitialized)

Removing it make it works.

```
void display_string(char *s1)
{
    int i;
    for (i =0; s1[i]; i++)
    {
        putchar(s1[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line `s1[i] = c;` in the function `display_string()`, it does nothing useful.

Also assigning a NULL value to a char is not correct. To terminate the array simply put `s[i] = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your display_string function needs a bit of work. You're overwriting the contents of the string instead of printing it. It might be worth finding out how to enable more compiler warnings. You have an obvious error that the compiler should be able to diagnose for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
void display_string(char *s1)
{
    int i;
    char c;
    for (i =0; s1[i]; i++)
    {
        s1[i] = c;
        putchar(s1[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

In this function you're overwriting your string characters with some undefined value of c, and THEN  trying to print that out. What you should do is just print that out.

Also, your code is very hard to read, because you're putting ??cleverness?? over **readibility** which is very, very bad habit. I mean the `while(string1[0]);` etc. If you use something like this - at least comment it. I highly doubt that You will remember what that means if you have to return to your code in month, a year or even more to change few things.

Answer (score 0):

The others answered the problem you were asking for, but your `read_string` has some flaws:
First, that function doesn't know how big your buffer is, it needs an additional argument:

```
void read_string(char *s, size_t length);
```

—this implies, that you should change the declaration of `i` to

```
size_t i;
```

—and this functions needs to check if the buffer pointed to by `s` is overflowed, like in:

```
for(i=0; i<size-1 && ( c=getchar() )!='\n'; ++i) /* ... */
```

`getchar` may also return `EOF`, which may be not representable as a `char` (if `char` is signed on your platform, this may even introduce undefined behaviour), so you should change your declaration to

```
int c;
```

and also check for `EOF`, like in:

```
for(i=0; i<size-1 && ( c=getchar() )!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i) /* ... */
```

and, (I'm not sure if this is standard conforming at all, at least, it's irritating):

```
s[i] = NULL;
```

should be changed to

```
s[i] = 0; // or '\0', if you prefer
```

you are not using a 0 pointer here.

HTH